# Proving a function whether decreasing or increasing

Tags: functions

Is $\log x!-2\log (\frac{x}{2})!$ a decreasing or an increasing function?

How we can proof what type a function this is?

-Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Stirling should give $x\log x-x -2[\frac{x}{2}\log(\frac{x}{2})-\frac{x}{2}] = x\log 2$ which is increasing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think I understood it with your comment and Mike's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be rewritten as $\log\binom{x}{x/2}$.  Does this help?

Comment: Since $\log\binom{x}{x/2}$ has a lower bound which is increasing... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Whoah, that's absurd reasoning. A decreasing function can have a lower bound that is increasing.

Comment: @mathworker21 If a function is non decreasing and has a lower bound that is increasing, then can we say it's increasing?